# Making a colorbox link appear on a mouseover that changes html content

Tags: jquery, colorbox, mouseover

I have a link (say, A) that changes to another link (B) once an option on the side navigation bar is hovered over. When clicking link A, the colorbox effect works great. However, when clicking on B (after the mouseover) the effect disappears.

To break down the problem to it's basics I have entered some code here below:

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function changeCode()
{
    $(".content").html('<p>Link B:<a class="iframe" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></p>');

}
</script>
...
<li onMouseover="changeCode();"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
...
<div class="content">
        <p>Link A:<a class="iframe" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></p>
</div>
```

Thank you to anyone who can provide some suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you simply place your `$(".iframe").colorbox(...)` code right after `$(".content").html(...)`?

Comment: Thanks mg007. I can't call that after because the $(".content").html(...) gets called in response to a mouseover, i.e. it calls changeCode().

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of event delegation. You're binding the colorbox tot he elements on DOM ready, however, you're removing the original element. The easiest way to do this is to simply change out some properties of the element, and not remove it completely.

```
$(".content").find('p').text('Link B').addBack().find('.iframe').prop('href', 'http://newsite.com');
```

Comment: Thank you, Ohgodwhy. I see what you mean. I actually need to change a chunk of text enclosed in a div tag. I put the "<p>Link B...</p>" as an example. However, I will try to apply your suggestion and see how I can work around it. Thanks again.